# Could not run phased build action using gradle distribution - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to import a gradle project but I keep getting this error:

> org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6-bin.zip'.
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.CompatProjectConnection$CompatModelBuilder.get(CompatProjectConnection.java:254)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.IdeAttachedProjectConnection.getModel(IdeAttachedProjectConnection.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.queryModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:114)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$null$0(DefaultModelProvider.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$GradleConnectionOperation.runInToolingApi(DefaultGradleBuild.java:328)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:57)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.withConnection(DefaultGradleBuild.java:121)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$fetchModel$1(DefaultModelProvider.java:48)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4878)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
>       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4873)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:89)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:47)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:458)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage.access$700(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage$UpdatePreviewOperation.runInToolingApi(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:479)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiOperations$1.runInToolingApi(ToolingApiOperations.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:57)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:32)
>       at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.internal.wizard.project.ProjectPreviewWizardPage$4.run(ProjectPreviewWizardPage.java:313)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
>       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.throwFailure(ProviderConnection.java:206)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:194)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:136)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:203)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.produceModel(PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder$1.run(DefaultModelBuilder.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>   Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1588)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
>       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:74)
>       ... 20 more

And In the problems section in Eclipse it says:

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6-bin.zip'.
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
>   invalid type code: 00

My os is linux Ubuntu 18.04. Any ideas?

Comment: For me, this easy solution solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548709/9974143

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. `ls -l ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`
2. `rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.6.bin.zip/`
3. And, do `sh gradlew` to download gradle dist under dists

Then restart Android Studio, and wait for download gradle bin.

Comment: "sh gradlew" did not work for me. Can you specify?

Comment: Hello, can you add the error? Are you using android studio? Alright?

Comment: I'm using VS code but this is in terminal so I don't think it matters. I do use mac though and not PC. The error is: Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.1-all.zip'.
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
invalid type code: 00

Comment: just saw that I wasn't running it from the android folder! add a step before step nr 3. "cd [path to projetc]/android

Answer (score 0):

first update gradle version to newest. more than 6.9

if not work,
Using dependencies as below it will resolve the error.

for gradle : `implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"`

[image: for gradle : implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"]

for maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image: for maven use below]