# Unable to open 'android': File is a directory

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
[{
    "resource": "/F:/e_commerce/android/",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip'.\r\nInitialization script 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\85fc10ae59c6b12d1658317ca9ffea4c\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.buildship.core\\init.d\\eclipsePlugin.gradle'\r\nCould not compile initialization script 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\85fc10ae59c6b12d1658317ca9ffea4c\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.buildship.core\\init.d\\eclipsePlugin.gradle'.\r\nstartup failed:\r\nGeneral error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60\r\njava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60\r\n\tat groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)\r\n\tat groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)\r\n\tat groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)\r\n\tat groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:70)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:57)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:234)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:231)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:242)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:199)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:122)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:912)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1280)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:252)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:113)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:89)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:128)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1099)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitClass(StaticImportVisitor.java:83)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:708)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1084)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:640)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:618)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:595)\r\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:401)\r\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)\r\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:341)\r\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:338)\r\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)\r\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:336)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:190)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:170)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:211)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:194)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:95)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:116)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:50)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)\r\n\tat org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:49)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:110)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)\r\n\tat org.gradle.configuration.DefaultInitScriptProcessor.process(DefaultInitScriptProcessor.java:50)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler$1.run(InitScriptHandler.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler.executeScripts(InitScriptHandler.java:51)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:33)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:59)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:42)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:220)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)\r\n\tat org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:67)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)\r\n\tat org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)\r\n\tat org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)\r\n\tat org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\r\n1 error",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this error show up on the debug console as well and this is what I did to remove it just a few minutes ago.

I am not completely sure if this solves the problem or what is causing the issue, but after doing these few things the error went away, so maybe it can help you too!

in `[./android/app/build.gradle]` I set the `jvmTarget` to '1.8':

```
...
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget '1.8' // <-- this

    }
...
```

and in `[./android/build.gradle]` I changed the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:` to 7.0.1

```
...

dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1' // <-- this
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

...
```

After that I ran `flutter clean` in the terminal and reloaded the IDE.

Just a little side note:

I had to manually change the `[./android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties]` file to use gradle 7.0.1.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.1-all.zip // <-- this
```